# How to use functions in R

Tags: r, function

I have a two column dataframe in R and i want to add a third column with values that are a function of the first two.
As long as the function is a simple mathematical formula no problem
`data$c <- data$a*15 - 10 + data$b*0.5`
But my function is non continous and contains conditionals, i would like to do:
`foo <- function(x,y){if (x<2) {return(0)} else {....}`
and 
`data$c <- foo(data$a, data$b)`
But this gets me errors. What am i missing?

Comment: Try to give more information when asking a question. If helps people help you.

Comment: This question is perfectly answerable as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = data.frame(a=rnorm(20),b=runif(20))

new_var = function(x,y)
{
  if(x<0)
  { x = x^2}
  else
  { x = x^3}

  if(y<.5)
  { -log10(y)}
  else
  {
    exp(y)
  }
  return((2*(x+y))/x*y)
}

df$c = sapply(1:length(df$a), function(i){new_var(df$a[i],df$b[i])})

head(df)
            a          b          c
1 -0.09149107 0.04834675 0.65517298
2 -2.43732351 0.04086087 0.08228385
3 -1.69573283 0.54795413 1.30474339
4 -0.40106220 0.72952356 8.07641367
5 -0.38244706 0.65524147 7.18118555
6  0.76334945 0.38455655 1.43404971
```

Comment: Don't forget to upvote answers you think are good. Chris's answer, fyi is prob more efficient in terms of time and cpu usage. If you had posted up your function we could have provided more help!

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `ifelse` function. First create a data frame:

```
> d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(5), y=rnorm(5))
> d
           x           y
1 -0.3581471  0.18149804
2  0.5096839  0.01260114
3  0.6742558  1.04851531
4  1.0761349 -0.17504221
5 -0.2373933 -1.11475886
```

Now create an extra column using `ifelse`:

```
> d$z <- ifelse(d$x < 0, 0, d$y + 1)
> d
           x           y         z
1 -0.3581471  0.18149804 0.0000000
2  0.5096839  0.01260114 1.0126011
3  0.6742558  1.04851531 2.0485153
4  1.0761349 -0.17504221 0.8249578
5 -0.2373933 -1.11475886 0.0000000
```